# Do I need a green card if I want to find an investor for my startup?

Tags: investing, investment-strategies, start-up, venture-capital, fund-raising

Should I either wait until I get my Green Card( maybe 6 months) or can I reach to investors with my EAD card if I have a complete mobile application ready to launch + a business plan for that?

PS: I am on F visa. Have an approved I-140 petition for EB-2 Green Card and also got my EAD card recently.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for an immigration attorney. You provided no details to the question and why you're asking it. Green card is a US permanent residency, you absolutely do not need to be a US permanent resident (or resident at all) to reach out to investors. EAD is, I assume, "Employment Authorization Document", which sounds similarly irrelevant for investors.

Comment: @littleadv: I am asking to see if investors care about the immigration status of an entrepreneur or not!

Comment: The investors care if you're able to do what you tell them you're going to do. In any case, I suggest you talk to your attorney.

Comment: Note that you could register a company in the US without even being present there. You could find US investors for a company not in the US. In many cases you could run a company in the US without being present there. You could also have the company have branches outside the US. So investing in a company doesn’t necessarily require you to have any status in the US. The only question is, if you run the company while you are in the US, what status do you need? And that is an immigration question, which would be better on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/